# What is the type of the lambda term $\lambda a.a(\lambda yt.t)(ya)$?

Tags: lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

I was given an exercise that asked me to assign a simple type to the lambda term:
$$
\lambda a.a(\lambda yt.t)(ya)
$$
but I couldn't find one, furthermore, the lambda term seems untypable to me because of the double reference to $a$.

This is my reasoning:

- let $t$ be of type $\alpha$, then $\lambda t.t$ has type $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$;
- let then $y$ have type $\beta$, and so $\lambda yt.t$ has type $\beta \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$;
- let now give $a$ the type $\beta \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$, in order for the term $a(\lambda yt.t)$ to be of type $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$.

From here I want $(ya)$ to be of type $\alpha$, so that the final term $a(\lambda yt.t)(ya)$ has a well-defined type, but the problem is that $y$ and $a$ both have already some defined types, which are not compatible (I cannot apply $a$ to $y$). However I assign types to $y$ and $a$, and I cannot find a type compatibility.

Can you please help me out? Is the lambda term typable in the first place? And if so, where am I wrong?

Comment: As a gentle suggestion, any Haskell or OCaml compiler will be able to find any simple type, should one exist.

Comment: There's also the matter of that $y$ variable which seems to be out of scope in your term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful: the two $y$ aren't “the same”, there's a bound one and a free one. You should first perform an α-equivalence step to rename the former:
$$\lambda a.a(\lambda yt.t)(ya) =_α λa.a(λzt.t)(ya). $$

Also, in the third step you make an erroneous assumption: by assigning to $a$ the type $\beta \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$, you assume that $(ya)$ is of type $α$ and that the whole term is also of type $α$ (*ie.* have the same type as $t$). There is no reason why this should be the case.

Let's start again from the beginning:

- $λzt.t$ is of type $β\to α\to α$ for some $α,β$,
- $(ya)$ is of type $\delta$, where $y$ is of type $\gamma \to \delta$ and $a$ is of type $\gamma$, for somme $\gamma,\delta$,
- then $a(λzt.t)$ must be of type $\delta\to\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon$,
- then $a$ must be of type $(β\to α\to α)\to \delta \to \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon$,
- and finally the whole term is of type $((β\to α\to α)\to \delta \to \epsilon) \to \epsilon$.

$\gamma$ disappeared but we know it is equal to $((β\to α\to α)\to \delta \to \epsilon) \to \delta$.

However, instead of writing the proof like this, you should write a derivation tree which would enable you to keep better track of the context (*ie.* the type of the free variables in subterms).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Yes, I know about the tree structure to solve the problem but I didn't know how to write it here. I didn't think about the two y as different variables, but now everything makes sense. Thanks again!